# How to use django view with jquery autosave?

Tags: jquery, django

I have a very long formset that is displayed to the page. It is currently saved like so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    survey_formset = SurveyFormset(request.POST)

    if survey_formset.is_valid():
        ss = SurveySet()
        ss.user=request.user
        ss.save()
        for form in survey_formset.forms:
            saved = form.save(commit=False)
            saved.surveyset = ss
            saved.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

How can I make it so the entire surveyset gets saved in the background every time the user fills in another input?

So far this what I have so far. How do I use callbacks to send stuff to the server via AJAX?

```
    <form action="" method="POST" id="surveyset">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ survey_formset.management_form|crispy }}

        <!--  A lot of inputs!  -->

          {% for form in survey_formset.forms %}
              <hr>
              <div id="survey-{{ forloop.counter }}" class='content'>
                {% crispy form %}
              </div>
          {% endfor %}

        <input id='save_set' type="submit" value="Submit" class='button' />
    </form>

<!-- Time to autosave! -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery.autosave.js" %}"></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready( function() {

      $("form").autosave({
        callbacks: {
          trigger: ["change", function() {
            var self = this;

            $("#save_set").click(function() {
              self.save();
            });

          }],
          save: {
            method: "ajax",

            // What do I tell the django view? 
            // How do I silently save in the background?

            options: {
              success: function() {
                console.log("saved!");
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });

    }); 
</script>
```

I am using this guys code:

https://github.com/nervetattoo/jquery-autosave

Comment: Probably your looking at saving a subset of a form. More on that here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: I think I want to add a few lines here: `save: {
            method: "ajax",
            options: {
              success: function() {
                console.log("saved!");
              }
            }
          }` to get all my POST data to get processed by a view in the background. But I only want one new surveyset to be created.

Comment: That is you want to save all the data the user has typed in ? if so that is the save comimit=False can be used to save the partial model

Comment: I am using commit=False... What I want to do is modify the view and the javascript in the template to talk to each other in the background using ajax.

Comment: Ah, you need to put in the URL in your save method there. url:"/path/to/view"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides a handy [is_ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) method on its `HttpRequest` objects that tells you whether the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header was set. Since the autosave plugin uses [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it will send this by default.

Just make sure you either:

- [Set the correct CSRF token in JavaScript](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)

or:

- Use the [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator on your view. (This is not recommended usually and should be used with caution.)

You can use this in your view to create a part of it that will handle the AJAX requests appropriately:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    # TODO: Handle autosave plugin save requests
    pass
 else:
    # this is where the normal stuff you already have happens
    ...
```

With the autosave plugin, the [save callback](https://github.com/nervetattoo/jquery-autosave#save) takes the same options as jQuery's AJAX method. A typical setup looks like this:

```
{ url: "http://yourdomain.com/your-view",
  data: {"key_for_server1": var1, "key_for_server2": var2},
  success: function() { 
            // pop up a nice green 'Saved!' message 
  },
  error: function() { 
            // alert "Oh, no! It didn't work!" 
  }
}
```

There are a ton of options you can set detailed in the documentation I linked above, and the autosave plugin passes them straight through so you can tell it all the same things.

The main ones, above, are the `url` to send data to (whatever is in `urls.py` for your view), `data` which is the actual `POST` data you will send (later found in the `request.post` dict), and the `success`, `complete`, and `error` callbacks, which are functions that handle those respective conditions.

Note that it will consider a success or failure based on the HTTP status code of the server response. So, e.g., if you `raise Http404` (don't -- just an example) it would call `error`, but if you return a normal `HttpResponse` (normally JSON) it will call `success`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a lot to take in, I will mark this as correct after getting it to work.