# How to use the jQuery autosave function with Django view to get DATA and save it

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

This is a follow up to my previous question,

[How to use django view with jquery autosave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675543/how-to-use-django-view-with-jquery-autosave)

I have this in my view:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    # Somehow begin to partially save the surveyset!
    return HttpResponse('why hello there')
if request.method == 'POST':

    survey_formset = SurveyFormset(request.POST)

    if survey_formset.is_valid():
        ss = SurveySet()
        ss.user=request.user
        ss.save()
        for form in survey_formset.forms:
            saved = form.save(commit=False)
            saved.surveyset = ss
            saved.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

And this on my template:

```
      $("form").autosave({
        callbacks: {
          trigger: ["change", function() {
            var self = this;

            $("#save_set").click(function() {
              self.save();
            });

          }],
          save: {
            method: "ajax",
            // How do I send this to my django view?
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/screen_many/",
            data: {'l':[1,2,3]},
            options: {
              success: function(response) {
                console.log("got: "+response);
              },
              error: function(e) {
                console.log('CRAP!');
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }); // end autosave
```

But I don't know how to get the data out. Whenever I click something it logs my reply... and that's via a `GET` request that submits:

```
e_1:2
e_2:3
e_3:1
i_1:5
i_2:4
form-4-cei_7:on
```

Which is in the URL...

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/screen_many/?e_1=2&e_2=3&e_3=1&i_1=5&i_2=4#
```

I just don't understand what is going on. What I am hoping to get is something like

```
cei_0: True
```

If I check a checkbox. Or maybe the whole survey_set? And I could continually update it?

EDIT: This is how I create my formset... using forms.py, and a helper method for my view

```
def ids_to_students(items, prefix=''):
    """Converts request items into a queryset.

    Usage:
        >>> students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items())
        >>> e_students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items(), 'e')

    Args:
        items: A dict of request.GET.items().
        prefix: A prefix for DB entries.

    Returns:
        A queryset.
    """
    # Make ordered QuerySets of Students based on their ids.
    prefixes = ['%s_' % prefix] if prefix else ['e_', 'i_']
    tuples = sorted(item for item in items if item[0][:2] in prefixes)

    pk_list = [v for (k, v) in tuples]
    clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(pk_list)])
    ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses
    students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).extra(
            select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering', ))
    return students

@login_required
def screen_many(request):

    # GET looks like ?e_1=2&e_2=3&e_3=1&i_1=5&i_2=4
    students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items())

    e_students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items(), 'e')
    i_students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items(), 'i')

    # Make a survey set with the students
    SurveyFormset = formset_factory(SurveyForm, extra=0)

    # Build a dataset of students with there associated behavior types.
    data =  [{'student':s.id, 'behavior_type': 'E'} for s in e_students]
    data += [{'student':s.id, 'behavior_type': 'I'} for s in i_students]

    survey_formset = SurveyFormset(initial=data)

    survey_count = len(students)

    # Make each form layout unique
    for f, kid in zip(survey_formset[0:len(students)], students):
        f.helper.layout = Layout(
                Field('student', type='hidden'),
                Field('surveyset', type='hidden'),
                Field('behavior_type', type='hidden'),
                Fieldset('Critical Events Index',
                        HTML("""
                        # ...
                        """),
                    ),
                )

    if request.is_ajax():
        # Somehow begin to partially save the surveyset!
        return HttpResponse('why hello there')


    if request.method == 'POST':

        survey_formset = SurveyFormset(request.POST)

        if survey_formset.is_valid():
            ss = SurveySet()
            ss.user=request.user
            ss.save()
            for form in survey_formset.forms:
                saved = form.save(commit=False)
                saved.surveyset = ss
                saved.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


    formsetWithStudents = zip(survey_formset.forms, students)

    c = {
         'formsetWithStudents' : formsetWithStudents,
         'students' : students,
         'survey_count' : survey_count,
         'e_students': e_students,
         'i_students': i_students,
         'survey_formset': survey_formset,
        }
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response("reports/screen_many.html", c)
```

and forms.py

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        exlude = 'cei_total','aggbs_total','si_total','cfiab_total','cfimb_total'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        super(SurveyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How are you creating the formset?

Comment: @Bibhas, I added the formset creation code for you. I use formset_factory.